# WindowServer[250]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: No matching context for device (0x7fcfcaf18220) - disabling OpenGL

Tags: display

I'm getting vast amounts of these messages in my Console:

```
13/03/2015 16:02:20.924 WindowServer[250]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: No matching context for device (0x7fcfcaf18220) - disabling OpenGL
```

and WindowServer is consistently at around 16%. I'm using DisplayLink. Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to `/etc/asl.conf` and then `kill -hup syslog`:

```
# WindowServer messages about display context (caused by DisplayLink driver)
? [= Sender WindowServer] [= Level Warning] [A= Message _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice] claim only
```

More about this here: http://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=62987&page=4

---

In case the explanation above is too cryptic:

1. Open Terminal
2. run `SUDO_EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano sudo -e /etc/asl.conf`
3. Use the arrow keys to scroll to the bottom of the file
4. Paste the text from above (the two lines starting with # and ?) into the Terminal window
5. Type <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> and confirm with <kbd>Y</kbd>
6. run `sudo kill -hup syslog`

Comment: Would someone be kind enough to update the code statement for use with OS X Yosemite? The above doesn't work at all and the message is: -bash: ?: command not found

Comment: @DarrenStevens You don't run this as a command. Put it into /etc/asl.conf and then run (in the terminal, not the file) kill -hup syslog.

Comment: Note that this will be deleted after any update, since asl.conf is majorly used, and updates may break it.

Comment: @awesomebing1 that's mentioned in the link I gave. There was a comment about using asl modules but apparently this did not work.

Comment: Doesn't the `SUDO_EDITOR` variable get set in the user shell and then ignored when sudo runs? I have to `sudo nano /etc/asl.conf` to avoid `vi` on my Macs.... Great answer +1