# Code to fix: WindowServer[250]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: No matching context for device (0x7fcfcaf18220) - disabling OpenGL

Tags: macos, display, kernel-panic

I need help implementing the answer to [WindowServer[250]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: No matching context for device (0x7fcfcaf18220) - disabling OpenGL](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176572/windowserver250-cgxgldisplaycontextfordisplaydevice-no-matching-context-for/176709#176709) by inserting the following into wherever it goes:

```
? [= Sender WindowServer] [= Level Warning] [A= Message _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice] claim only
```

I'm not a coder but I can get to Terminal and past in code and press enter.  That's the extent of my ability.  So, if there's something to do before putting this statement in Terminal I would need to know what, where, and how, etc.  Thank you.

Comment: The original answer has been edited, should be more obvious now how you can change the file.

Answer (score 1):

From the original answer:

Type the following into your terminal: `sudo nano /etc/asl.conf`.
Now, use the arrow key to go to the bottom. When you are at the bottom, paste it the following:

```
? [= Sender WindowServer] [= Level Warning] [A= Message _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice] claim only
```

(There is nothing special, just command+v).

Now, hit control+x and hit y. Now, type `sudo kill -hup syslog`.

Sudo means super user grant, so you are giving the command access to all of your machine.

Comment: Could I encourage you to edit the original answer directly with the above, more detailed description on how to change `asl.conf`? We probably don't need to questions for the same topic, I would then close this one here as a duplicate.

Comment: @patrix Okay. I'll pull it up.

Comment: @patrix According to it, my answer changes too much.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'll try myself then :-)

Comment: @patrix Could you mention http://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=62987&page=4? I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Didn't exactly work the way it was described but I tried my best. Let's see if I get more kernel panics. Thanks.